# Powershell - Check if user is memberof group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm starting my first steps in powershell and i want to create an api, to check if a user is memberof a group

In my first example i'm using this

```
#Start Pode Server
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Start-PodeServer -Threads 20 {
    #Attach port 8000 to the local machine address and use HTTP protocol
    Add-PodeEndpoint -Address 192.168.60.30 -Port 8083 -Protocol HTTP
    #Create route and return a static value
    Add-PodeRoute -Method Get -Path '/static' -ScriptBlock {
        $data = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity itchart -Recursive -Server stie2.articatech.local | Where-Object {$_. SamAccountName -eq "admin2"}
        if($data.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-PodeTextResponse -Value 'false'  -Cache -MaxAge 1800
        }
        else {
            Write-PodeTextResponse -Value 'true' -Cache -MaxAge 1800
        }  
    }
}
```

But i notice than each query takes about 50ms or more.

Is there anyway to speed is up? Pherpas using anothe module as webserver or changing the powershell query.

Thanks in adavance
André Bolinhas

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` will be costly time wise. You will need to look at coding in logic to cache the results and the max age of this cache, you'll also need to design in a repository for your cache such as a database.

Comment: Any other function instead Get-ADGroupMember that give me the same result and cost less? Is not mandatory to be in poweshell, maybe .net or c# could give me more performance

Comment: Use an ldap filter: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(samaccountname=user)(memberof=groupDN))'`. I'm a bit rusty on my ldap queries, but this should work. So, if it returns something that means they're a part of it, else they're not.

Comment: This could be a good aproach, but it only search in the primary domain controller, not in all forest

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417611/unable-to-retrieve-cross-domain-users-with-get-adgroupmember-recursive) might be helpful.

Comment: Just specify the global catalog port `-Server stie2.articatech.local:3268`